# How to encrypt text using openssl and PBEWithMD5AndDES?

Tags: openssl, jasypt

What is an openssl equivalent of using jasypt with algorithm PBEWithMD5AndDES?

Example using jasypt:

```
java -cp ~/.m2/repository/org/jasypt/jasypt/1.9.2/jasypt-1.9.2.jar  org.jasypt.intf.cli.JasyptPBEStringEncryptionCLI input="contactspassword" password=supersecretz algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES                                                   

----ENVIRONMENT-----------------                                                                                                                                                                  
Runtime: Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.112-b15                                                                                                        
----ARGUMENTS-------------------                                                                                      
algorithm: PBEWithMD5AndDES                                                                                                                                                                        
input: contactspassword                                                                                               
password: supersecretz                                                                              
----OUTPUT----------------------

H4usVG7JPI7wwbUeLUVZ3x+nJY17LCnvlA254v355Cw=
```